# Advice for modelling a shirt tied at the waist

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model a wide shirt tied around a character's waist. I'm very new to Blender so there might be some tools to help me with this that I don't know about.

Since I wanted the shirt to be also wearable when untied, I modelled it that way first:

[image]

edit: Here is the reference sheet I made, and a picture of what I'm trying to model. The model for the shirt would use a cloth simulation in the finished product, be tied in a knot, and the sleeves' tips would need to be triangle shaped. I've unfortunately deleted my attempts as I went, but I shared my latest attempt down below. The main problem I keep running into is how to twist the sleeves into a knot without moving the rest of the shirt and without ending up with the sleeves just clipping into each other.

[image][image][image]

Comment: as you can see in the overwhelming comments and answers - your question isn't self explanatory at all. Please add at least an image how your end result should look like. And also showing some effort (what you tried) is showing us that you don't look for anyone who does your work. And 2nd thing is: this site is specifically for one specific problem, not for tutorials. So you should focus on that ONE problem you have.

Comment: Hello and welcome. A sketch or reference image would be helpful to understand what you want the result to look like. Is the shirt tied with a belt or a knot? Have you tried a cloth simulation?

Comment: @Chris I've added reference images to the post. My main issue is with the sleeves that I try to move with the resize and move tools but can never get the shape I need and end up with the vertices clipping into each other. This is probably due to my limited experience with the software and there might even be some tools i don't know of for this exact purpose. I am looking for advice or guidance from someone with more experience, NOT for someone to do it for me. If this is not the right site to be asking this on, please do tell me so I can search elsewhere.

Comment: @Blunder I've added some reference images in an edit, the shirt is tied with a knot. I've applied the cloth physics modifier but this does not help me in modelling the tied shirt, unless there's a feature I don't know about for what I'm trying to do. Thank you for taking the time to reply.